# Method for printing multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a method that takes any kind of multi-dimensional array, and returns it in a human-readable form as a String.

For example:

```
input 1:  [1, 2, 3]

output 1: { 1, 2, 3 }


input 2:  [[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5, 6]]

output 2: { 
             { 1, 2, 3 },
             {   },
             { 4, 5, 6 }
          }
```

So, the signature of the method is something like

```
String printArray(Object array)
{
   ...
}
```

So far, I figured out how to build it in a recursive manner. I wonder if it is possible to avoid recursion. Obviously, this is a matter of research, and won't be implemented in production.

Thanks

Edited:

OK. I guess it's easier to share the recursive implementation:

```
private String writeArray(Object array, String indent, String result)
{
    boolean isObjectArray = array.getClass().isArray();

    if (isObjectArray)
    {
        int length = Array.getLength(array);
        boolean isComponentArray = array.getClass().getComponentType().isArray();

        result += indent;
        result += (isComponentArray) ? "{\n" : "{ ";

        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            if (length != 0)
            {
                Object component = Array.get(array, i);
                result = writeArray(component, indent + "\t", result);
            }

            if (i < length - 1)
                result += (isComponentArray) ? ",\n" : ", ";
            else
                result += (isComponentArray) ? "\n" + indent + "}" : " }";

            i++;
        }
        while (i < length);
    }
    else
    {
        result += array.toString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This already exists as [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-), although the output format is slightly different from what you're producing. I believe that method is generally implemented recursively.

Comment: Unless there is a way to get the dimension of an array, I don't believe there is a way to do this non-recursively- you need some sort of stop condition.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for the quick response! I am aware of that method, and as you mentioned, it displays array in a linear manner. I need a slightly different format

Comment: Input 1 is just an array.  Input 2 is an array of arrays. So you can handle those separately by overloading.  Method 1 would take the single array and print it. Method 2 could first print `{`, then have a simple for loop that iterates over the array of arrays, prints your indentation and calls method 1 for each array.  Finally it prints `}` and done.

Comment: @Arjan I use this logic in my recursive implementation. The point is that if implemented iteratively, I don't know how to specify boundaries in a for loop.

Comment: The length of the array? `print '{';` ... `for (int k=0; k < arrayOfArrays.length; k++) { // print tab ;  printArray(arrayOfarrays[k]); }` ...  `print '}'` Why would that not work?

Comment: @Arjan I'm a bit confused. Apologies for misunderstanding. You mentioned printArray(arrayOfarrays[k]). Isn't this a recursive call? The whole point is to avoid recursion. You know the size of the external array (arrayOfArrays.length), but its elements (sub-arrays) might be of different size, so you have to set up different boundaries in inner loops

Comment: How do you want to format a 3-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd want to use iteration instead of recursion, you just need to realize that the `arrayOfArrays` has `arrayOfArrays.length` arrays.  And each sub array has `array.length` elements.

This is an example with arrays of `int`.

```
public class WhatChaMaCallIt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[]   arr1 = {1, 2, 3};
        int[][] arr2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {}, {10, 11} };

        System.out.println(print(arr1));
        System.out.println(print(arr2));
    }

    private static String print(int[] arr) {
        if (arr.length == 0) {
            return "{ }";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("{ ")
            .append(arr[0]);
        for (int k=1; k < arr.length; k++) {
            sb.append(", ")
                .append(arr[k]);
        }
        sb.append(" }");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String print(int[][] arrOfArrs) {
        if (arrOfArrs.length == 0) {
            return "{ }";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("{\n");
        sb.append("    ")
            .append(print(arrOfArrs[0]));
        for (int k=1; k < arrOfArrs.length; k++) {
            sb.append(",\n")
                .append("    ")
                .append(print(arrOfArrs[k]));
        }
        sb.append("\n}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Output

```
{ 1, 2, 3 }
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 },
    { },
    { 10, 11 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Arjan for your suggestion. The code you provided is good for 1-D or 2-D arrays. But it won't work for array with a higher dimension. For example,

int[][][] arr2 = {
   {
           {1, 2, 3},
           {4, 5, 6},
           {7, 8, 9},
          },
          {
           {10, 11, 12},
           {13, 14, 15},
           {16, 17, 18},
          },
         };